npm ETIMEDOUT when installing packages on VPS server in just one project
I have an Ubuntu VPS server hosting some projects, but one of them is getting an error when running npm install.
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte-inspector/-/vite-plugin-svelte-inspector-2.1.0.tgz failed, reason:
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

On the local machine (Windows 11 with WSL2), I can install the packages normally.
The package mentioned in the error changes sometimes.
I've tried restarting the server and deleting the proxy settings, but nothing.
